# xml find is always None

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, elementtree

How can I use `.find` or `.get` to get the value what's I want?

I look at the example, I don’t know where I did it wrong

Always get None

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.ipc.com/ver10">
    <types>
        <bitRateType>
            <enum>VBR</enum>
            <enum>CBR</enum>
        </bitRateType>
        <quality>
            <enum>lowest</enum>
            <enum>lower</enum>
        </quality>
    </types>
    <streams type="list" count="2">
        <item id="0">
            <name type="string" maxLen="32"><![CDATA[rtsp://192.168.0.175:554/chID=2&streamType=main]]></name>
            <resolution>2592x1520</resolution>
        </item>
        <item id="1">
            <name type="string" maxLen="32"><![CDATA[rtsp://192.168.0.175:554/chID=2&streamType=sub1]]></name>
            <resolution>704x480</resolution>
        </item>
    </streams>
</config>
```

My Code.

```py
tree = ET.fromstring(res.text)
types = tree.find('types')
streams = tree.find('streams')
item = streams.findall('item')[0]
print(item.get('name'))
print(item.get('resolution'))
print(types, streams, item)
```

Comment: One thing you need to take into account is the namespace. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method's

```py
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
new_tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
new_root = new_tree.getroot()
types = new_root[0]
bitRateType = types[0]
quality = types[1]
streams = new_root[1]
item0_name = streams[0][0]
item0_resolution = streams[0][1]
item1_name = streams[1][0]
item1_resolution = streams[1][1]
print(item0_name.attrib)
print(item1_resolution.text)
```

*var*.attrib - all attributes, for example:

```py
print(item0_name.attrib)
{'type': 'string', 'maxLen': '32'}
```

*var*.text - get text , for example:

```py
print(item1_resolution.text)
704x480
```

Comment: This works, thank you.